# Do other vampires feel pleasure for being bitten (kissed)?

Tags: world-of-darkness, vampire-the-masquerade

So, the vampire's kiss induces some sort of pleasure (some would say, the most amazing kind).

Is there any statement that talks about if it works in supernatural beings (such as vampires themselves, kuei-jin, werebeasts or whatever)? Or does it only work on humans? And if so, do Mages count as mortal/humans for that matter?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Yes, they find it pleasurable, and anything with blood is prone to it

If you don't mind, I'm going to cite V20 for my answer:

Page 269, **Earning Blood Pool**

> Indeed, the ecstasy caused by the vampire’s bite is called the Kiss, and it engenders
>   as much exquisite, subtly painful pleasure in vampires as it does in mortals.Exceptionally strong-willed mortals (9+ Willpower) may continue to resist, but even these vessels eventually succumb to the pleasure...

It only lists for Kindred an extra rule to escape:

> While Kindred find the Kiss pleasurable, they may resist it more readily than mortals can. Any Kindred, regardless of Willpower, may make a Self-Control/Instincts roll (difficulty 8) to avoid succumbing to the Kiss. This enables vampiric victims of diablerie (p. 293) to have a chance at fighting back.

If you follow to page 270, there is a table listing the maximum amount of blood points you can attain from a creature, which only has a scant few categories:

- Human (only adult vs. child)
- Kindred (by generation)
- Animal (mostly by size except for rats)
- Garou

Comment: When Mage/Vampire interaction is described, they are explicitly characterized as being like humans for purposes of blood drinking.

Comment: @CatLord would you know if it works with were-beasts too?

Comment: I believe if you're not a kindred, you need a Willpower 9+ to resist.  The furballs just have a larger blood pool so something interceding has a greater chance to do something.